# Is the single-use attitude-indicator tag necessary? Should it just be synonymized with instrument?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

This is about a reasonable tag that may be used so infrequently and has a good alternative that I wonder if we should cull it out of good tag hygene practice.

---

[What order were space shuttle roll-pitch-yaw angles displayed in?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49784/12102) is the only question with the [attitude-indicator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude-indicator) tag (1 question), but we do have an [instrument](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument) tag (46 questions) which (probably) applies to a whole variety of displays and indicators that convey information to a spacecraft pilot.

Is the [attitude-indicator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude-indicator) tag the best choice for and indicator displaying information to astronauts during spaceflight? Or should it be replaced with [instrument](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument) and allowed to fade away and out of visibility/use.

It's not a bad tag, but I wonder if it is a one-off tag that is not likely to be used again, so maybe synonymize it to [instrument](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument)?

Or instead should we do the opposite and add it to more attitude indicator questions, there must be at least a few, including

- [How are physical attitude indicators actuated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39123/12102)
- [Orion cockpit instrumentation](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35047/12102)
- [What instruments are necessary aboard spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1427/12102)
- [Calculation of V1 (orbital speed) during ascent](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35045/12102)

---

[image: attitude-indicator] [image: attitude-indicator]

[image: attitude-indicator] [image: attitude-indicator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been involved in asking and answering some of these questions.  In my opinion, it is too specific and infrequent to merit its own tag.

Comment: If it stays just one question and this answer gets a third vote with no disagreements, just go ahead and retag the question.

Comment: @called2voyage that seems to have been done, and the tag currently has no questions. Is the "completed" tag called for in this case? (I just don't know)

Comment: I'll look into this tomorrow

Comment: I added the synonym!